# Change date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example which finds the difference of days between 2 specified dates and works only in Chrome, I think in firefox 6 and IE8 it does not support the format of date that I am using (shows `NaN`). Can somebody help me change the format to desired 1 (see below)?

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/5/)

**My format** : `2011-08-18 11:49:01`

**Desired format** : `08-18-2011 11:49:01`

My Code

```
var cellvalue="2011-08-18 11:49:01.0 IST";
var firstDate = new Date();
var secondDate = cellvalue.substring(0, cellvalue.length-4);
alert(diffOf2Dates(firstDate,secondDate));
function diffOf2Dates(todaysDate,configDate)
{
/*var udate="2011-08-18 11:49:01.0";
var configDate=new Date(udate);*/

var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = todaysDate; // Todays date
var secondDate = new Date(configDate);

var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));


return Math.ceil(diffDays);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Datejs library with great results when having to work with dates in various formats. Give it a go: http://www.datejs.com

Comment: Hi I used it, but gives me error `Date.friday is not a function` I used `var test=Date.friday();` and later `console.info` to print it in firebug. I included the script file, I saw it in fiddler too. Whats the problem here?

Comment: Thanks `Date.parse(configDate);` solved my problem but still `Date.friday();` is not working :(

Comment: Indeed you are right. I followed a few examples on their homepage and apparently `Date.today().friday()` does the trick.